# doing "Smart" search in DataTables in Shiny (searching multiple keywords)

Tags: r, search, datatables, shiny, dt

I am trying to use "smart"search in a datatable in a shiny app, so that multiple keywords can be searched wherever they appear in the table.
This is a default functionality for datatables according to https://datatables.net/reference/option/search.smart , and it certainly works when datatables are run in R outside a shiny app. But when I embed a datatable in a shiny app this functionality doesn't work. Is there an option to enable it, or a workaround?

My table has a column with long text, in which the user would search for different (random) keywords.

Below is a code that can be tested. Searching for "Compact Honda" gives multiple results in R rendered table, but none in shiny.

```
####### shiny basic script

    library(ggplot2) #to load mpg dataset
    library(shiny)

    ui <- fluidPage(
      fluidRow(
        DT::dataTableOutput("table")
      )

)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable({
    mpg
  }))
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)



####### R basic script

library(ggplot2) #to load mpg dataset

DT::datatable(mpg)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for you:

```
####### shiny basic script

library(ggplot2) #to load mpg dataset
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    DT::dataTableOutput("table")
  )

)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable({
    mpg, server = TRUE
  }))
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I have added an argument `server = TRUE` to the `datatable()`, it is important to use server-side `DT` (server - side processing), so all the  functionalities work well.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried the code with the modification you did, but the search is still treated as a phrase rather than as keywords. Might I be missing something?